# Count days with records per customer in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, distinct

Let's say I've got the following data (notice the id to dates diff):

```
customer_id  created_at
1000         2017-12-29 20:48:54+00
1000         2017-12-30 12:48:56+00
1000         2017-12-30 12:49:26+00
1002         2017-12-30 12:52:36+00
1001         2017-12-30 12:54:15+00
1002         2017-12-30 13:54:15+00
1001         2017-12-30 13:56:58+00
1000         2018-01-02 13:01:13+00
1001         2018-01-02 20:29:19+00
1002         2018-01-02 20:29:31+00
1000         2018-01-03 20:30:28+00
1001         2018-01-03 20:38:40+00
```

I want to get the number of days in which a customer has made a record. If a customer has made multiple records for a day, then it still counts as 1. So, the output of the above data should be:

```
customer_id  count
1000         4
1001         3
1002         2
```

I've tried different queries where I try to make use of `to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-mm-dd')` and `DISTINCT ON(created_at)` and `count`, but I am not getting the aggregated result that I would like. F.e.:

```
SELECT distinct on (to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-mm-dd')) count(customer_id), customer_id
FROM registration 
WHERE created_at >= '2017-12-29' and created_at <= '2018-01-03' and customer_id in (1000,1001,1002)
group by customer_id, created_at;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct` in a derived table (a subquery in the `from` clause):

```
select customer_id, count(created_at)
from (
    select distinct customer_id, created_at::date
    from registration
    ) s
group by 1
order by 1;

 customer_id | count 
-------------+-------
        1000 |     4
        1001 |     3
        1002 |     2
(3 rows)
```

Actually user 1001 was active for 3 days, not 4.

Comment: Yep, it's 3 not 4. :D The machine calculates better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT`:

```
WITH sample (customer_id, created_at) AS (
    VALUES
        (1000, '2017-12-29 20:48:54+00'::TIMESTAMP),
        (1000, '2017-12-30 12:48:56+00'),
        (1000, '2017-12-30 12:49:26+00'),
        (1002, '2017-12-30 12:52:36+00'),
        (1001, '2017-12-30 12:54:15+00'),
        (1002, '2017-12-30 13:54:15+00'),
        (1001, '2017-12-30 13:56:58+00'),
        (1000, '2018-01-02 13:01:13+00'),
        (1001, '2018-01-02 20:29:19+00'),
        (1002, '2018-01-02 20:29:31+00'),
        (1000, '2018-01-03 20:30:28+00'),
        (1001, '2018-01-03 20:38:40+00')    
)
SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT created_at::DATE) 
FROM 
    sample 
GROUP BY 
    customer_id
```